# Getting capybara/cucumber and poltergeist to work with twitter bootstrap modal dialog box

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, integration-testing, phantomjs, poltergeist

**Context:**
I'm testing a rails app with Cucumber/Capybara/PhantomJS/Poltergeist.  I have a click_link call in one of my cucumber step definition files.  This click_link call then results in Rails calling the show method of a controller.  The controller finds an object by a particular id and responds in javascript format (format.js).  The response, given by the show.js.erb file, then performs some text string substitution on a Twitter Bootstrap modal dialog box to show a custom status message in the box.  The modal dialog box is then displayed.

This all works in production.  But it doesn't seem to work in testing.  I get an error message " no button with value or id or text 'Close' found (Capybara::ElementNotFound)".  Also, puts page.html simply displays this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
```

which makes me think the modal dialog box is never being shown at all.  Anyone have any ideas as to what's going on?

**cucumber_steps.rb**

```
When /^I click this link$/ do

  click_link "Some link to call show method"

  puts page.html

end

And /^I click close button in the modal box$/ do

   click_button 'Close'

end
```

**HTML in page for modal box for Twitter Bootstrap:**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/kites/24" data-remote="true">Some link to call show method</a></li>
</ul>
 :
 :
    <form>

<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-header">

    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>

    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>

  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">

    <p>One fine body…</p>

  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">

    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>

    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>

  </div>

</div>

</form>
```

**Rails show method**

```
def show

    @kite = Kite.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|

      format.js

    end

  end
```

Answer (score 2):

### Close Button Error

You're getting the error because you're using `click_button "Close"` and the click button doesn't use "Close" for its id or text:
`<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>`

To get around error you're getting back I would do the following:

```
close_button = page.find('button.close')
click_button close_button
```

### General Issue

You've left out a lot of details on your immplementation so it's hard to pin point where you've gone wrong. The first thing I'd check is to ensure [you have poltergeist set up](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist#installation) in you `env.rb` file